# Do we say "in" or "at" one's approach?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

The specific sentence is:

> "Nasreddin Hodja is simple **at/in** his approach."

Meaning that the way he thinks on a specific subject is simple and practical.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Google hits for the searches "simple in his approach" and "simple at his approach" number 53 900 : 0.

Comment: In your example sentence it would be "in", but in other cases "at his approach" might apply.

Comment: @nnnnnn - If he's coming toward you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct idiom would be "in his approach."

Likewise, to make N. the subject following an adverbial clause, "In his approach, N. is simple and practical."